# ASP.NET C# Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to populate a GridView using a method called PopulateGrid() (below) but keep getting the same server error "Must Declare the scalar variable "@QUALID".

```
public void PopulateGrid()
    {
        String val = TextBox2.Text;

        String sql = "SELECT QLEVELNAME FROM Qual_Levels WHERE QUALID=@QUALID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,
           new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RecruitmentDBConnString"].ConnectionString));
        
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("QUALID", val));

        cmd.Connection.Open();


        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cmd.Connection);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "Qual_Levels");


        SelectionGrid.DataSource = ds;
        SelectionGrid.DataBind();


        ds.Dispose();
        da.Dispose();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }
```

The GridView is being declared like so..

```
<asp:GridView ID="SelectionGrid"
            autogeneratecolumns="False" 
            runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="QUALID">
            
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QLEVELNAME" HeaderText="Level Name" 
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="name" />
            </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

After trying countless things and trawling through the forums I keep coming up against the same error.

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@QUALID".
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare
> the scalar variable "@QUALID".
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 282:            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
>
> Line 283:            da.Fill(ds, "Qual_Levels");

If anyone can shed any light on the situation I would be really grateful!

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, general consensus seems to be I'm missing the @ in my sql param but have tried and the same error is being thrown. Also i have the exact same syntax as originally posted for my dropdown lists which are working ok.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("QUALID", val));
```

should be this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUALID", val));
```

---

Sorry, typed too quick, try:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QUALID", val);
```

---

OK, you have a slightly more fundamental issue in your code.  You create a command object, but then you pass the SQL string and the connection for the command into your dataadapter, where it will execute your sql string with no parameters on it's connection.

I haven't used dataadapters too much, but I think you need to set the parameters on the select command of your adapter.

Comment: same error again! I think these are all valid options which leads me to think it's being caused somewhere else. Wish I knew where!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the @ to your sql param like so

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUALID", val));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "@" where you add the parameter:

```
SqlParameter("@QUALID", val)
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("QUALID", val));
```

to either

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUALID", val));
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QUALID", SqlDbType.WhatFitsYourDB).Value = val;
```

and you should be good to go. Your problem is that you are missing a '@' in the paramter name

Answer (score 1):

```
String val = TextBox2.Text;

String sql = "SELECT QLEVELNAME FROM Qual_Levels WHERE QUALID=@QUALID";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RecruitmentDBConnString"].ConnectionString));
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cmd.Connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@QUALID", val));

da.SelectCommand = cmd;
cmd.Connection.Open();

da.Fill(ds, "Qual_Levels");


SelectionGrid.DataSource = ds;
SelectionGrid.DataBind();

ds.Dispose();
da.Dispose();
cmd.Connection.Close();
cmd.Connection.Dispose();
```

use dis one it will work...(`da.selectcommand = cmd;`)

Comment: This is indeed a possible solution, I'm gonna necro this just to explain in short. The OP had an SqlCommand object but never used it. An even easier fix is `new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)` initialising the adapter using the selectcommand object instead of the "sql" string. PS: using three letter variable names isn't nice either, try objCommand & strSql and double the readability (in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

If using dropdown list you need to add selected value inside :

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind ("QUALID") %>'
```