# Using Textbox and button on master page with validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am very new to programing and have a steep learning curve ahead of me.

I am creating a new interface with our SQL Server 2008 databases (3) using asp.net 4 and C#.

I have referenced several posts here on stack overflow that have helped as well as  this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5z00s5e(v=vs.90).aspx).

I have created a master page where the user selects which database.

The first interface I am working on is a basic

```
SELECT * FROM (table) WHERE SER_NO = @SER_NO
```

The user enters a 6 digit (int) into a textbox (`TB3`). `TB3` is to be validated with a custom validator to verify that the serial number is in the database. I would like the box to turn red if the number is not found and green if it is (nice not needed). Then the user clicks a button to display all the records of that device in a grid view.

Do I have to keep the textbox and Validator on the same page where it will be displayed?

Update 4/21

I have moved my textbox and validator to the same page as the display.  I am having trouble referencing the textbox from the masterpage.
Is there a way to reference the textbox from the mainpage and display the results on a different page that uses the same master page?

My display page code looks like this now:

```
    <asp:TextBox id="TB3" Text="Ser. No." runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="Val_TB3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TB3" OnServerValidate="Val_TB3_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Invalid Serial No." />
    <asp:GridView ID="MH_Grid" runat="server" AutoGertateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
    <asp:button ID="btn_MH" runat="server" Text="Maint Hist" OnClick="btnMH_Click" />
```

Then I was receiving a "WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'." Here [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660900/webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapping-for-jquery) is the answer for that problem. Thanks ericdc
I added to my web.config file:

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>
```

Update 4/23
Fixes for errors received:
Button fixed by recreating event and pasting code back in.

Fixed [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584217/asp-net-c-sharp-must-declare-the-scalar-variable)
Code behind updated below.

Fixed [Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212706/no-mapping-exists-from-object-type-system-web-ui-webcontrols-textbox-to-a-known)

Remaining problems are:
a.) useing a textbox and button from the master page.
b.) Validator only runs on button click for all buttons.

My code behind is this:

```
    public partial class Main_Hist : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void Val_TB3_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
           string MHVal = TB3.Text;
           using (SqlConnection MH_con = new SqlConnection(configurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MainHist"].ConnectionString))
           {
               SqlCommand MH_Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE SER_NO = @SERNO", MH_con);
               MH_con.Open();
               SqlDataReader reader = MH_Cmd.ExecuteReader();
               if(reader.HasRows)
               {
                   args.IsValid = true;
               }
               else
               {
                   args.IsValid = false;
               }
           }
        }
        protected void btnMH_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string MHSelect = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE SER_NO = @S_No";
            SQLConnection MHcon = SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainhist"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            MHcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(MHSelect, MH_con);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@S_No",TB3.Text);
            DataSet MHds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(MHds);
            if (MHds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                MH_Grid.DataSource = MHds;
                MH_Grid.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to database.");
            }
            MHcon.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any help and pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please indent your code (4 spaces). It's harder to read when its flat.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the validation code never actually queries the database. The line

> string returnValue = "SELECT SER_NO FROM table WHERE SER_NO = "
>   +TB3.Text + ";";

declares a string containing the query text, but you don't execute the query.

To execute a query that retrieves a single value from the db, you can create a SqlCommand object and call its ExecuteScalar method.

Comment: Your edits have changed the question a lot and added specific errors you're getting, so my answer now looks like nonsense! Anyway, I see you've now added a SqlCommand as I suggested, so I hope my answer was helpful to you and you feel able to click the "up" arrow. I'll try and look at your new problems later if I get a chance, if no-one else answers first.

Comment: yes it was helpful.  I will look into the ExecuteScalar method as soon as I get a chance.