# Link Dataset with SQL server : Fail

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, web

I've literally searched everything and everywhere but somehow this piece of code of mine just won't work no matter what I've tried.
So I have created a database on a SQL server and linked it, tested it, great it works. OK, so the problem is when I'm trying to insert data on a website textbox and have THAT data copied/transferred into my database table. So I only now get an error saying that 'Exception unhandeld and Must declare the scalar variable "@f_name". 
I would appreciate it if anyone can assist? Thanks.

```
 private void Save(string hfname, string hlname, string hemail, string hcomment)
        {
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            String sql = "INSERT INTO helpdesk (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Comments) VALUES " + " (@f_name, @l_name, @email, @comment)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConn);
            ITDBDataset itdbDataSet = new ITDBDataset();
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
            try
            {

                myConn.Open();
                dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dataAdapter.Fill(itdbDataSet);
                myConn.Close();

                SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];
                //para,[0]
                param[0] = new SqlParameter("@f_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                param[1] = new SqlParameter("@l_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                param[2] = new SqlParameter("@email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
                param[3] = new SqlParameter("@comment", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 600);

                param[0].Value = hfname;
                param[1].Value = hlname;
                param[2].Value = hemail;
                param[3].Value = hcomment;

                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Not Added, check context!";
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
            }
            //finally
            //{
            //    myConn.Close();
            //}
        }
```

Any suggestions to what could have gone wrong?

Comment: If you pass `null` as a value of a parameter, the parameter is ignored, you should instead pass `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: Try the solutions in this question.

[SQL parameters][1]


  [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584217/asp-net-c-sharp-must-declare-the-scalar-variable

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add the parameters to your command and you close the connection before the call of the method. I propose you using:

```
 private void Save(string hfname, string hlname, string hemail, string hcomment)
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        String sql = "INSERT INTO helpdesk (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Comments) VALUES " + " (@f_name, @l_name, @email, @comment)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConn);
        ITDBDataset itdbDataSet = new ITDBDataset();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
        try
        {

            myConn.Open();
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dataAdapter.Fill(itdbDataSet);


            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[6];
            //para,[0]
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@f_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@l_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@comment", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 600);

            param[0].Value = hfname;
            param[1].Value = hlname;
            param[2].Value = hemail;
            param[3].Value = hcomment;

            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);//add the parameters
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           myConn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) eg

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
String sql = 
     "INSERT INTO helpdesk (First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Comments) VALUES " + 
     " (@f_name, @l_name, @email, @comment)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, myConn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name",hfname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name",hlname);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",hemail);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment",hcomment);

ITDBDataset itdbDataSet = new ITDBDataset();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
try
{
        myConn.Open();
        dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dataAdapter.Fill(itdbDataSet);
        myConn.Close();
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{
        string msg = "Not Added, check context!";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
}
```